# What is SimStreamProcessorService?

Tags: macos

When you click on the battery in the menu bar in OS X it shows you how much battery power you have left. It also shows the processes that are using the most battery power.

But last week a process called SimStreamProcessorService showed up in that list. I don't know what that does. When I open up the activity monitor it does not show up in there, which means I can't shut it down. So I wanna know if this is malware or not.

**Does anyone know what SimStreamProcessorService is/does?**

Comment: You're using Apple Developer tools?

Comment: @Rob Yes, I am.

Comment: It's part of XPCServices, but unfortunately I cannot help you more than this.

Answer (score 4):

I had SimStreamProcessorService grabbing 33% of my CPU and a lot of memory. But at the time I also had an XCode simulator starting up for the first time, and the "iOS OS" was starting up in that simulator. Once the simulator came up to the home page, the SimStreamProcessorService stopped running.

Comment: As per your last line statement...this is not happened in my case